# Java: How to test if an input is a double or an int

Tags: java, if-statement, casting

I have a do while loop. Checking x is between two values. Now im supposed to be taking in an int value, but if the user types a double im getting exceptions. How do I incorparate a check in the same if statement so that if the user types a double it would print something like "x must be an int between 10 and 150:"

```
            do {
            x = sc.nextInt();
            if ( x < 10 || x > 150 ) {
                System.out.print("x between 10 and 150: ");
            } else {
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Why not just use `nextDouble` instead of `nextInt`? Then check whether the specified value is equal to its integer equivalent? Admittedly that would allow "100.000" as valid input - is that a problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo, but if you want your `x` to be _between_ 10 and 50, your condition is wrong. You should change it to `x > 10 || x < 150`

Comment: actually it should be x>10 && x<150...

Comment: @JonSkeet This doesn't solve his problem that the Scanner method may throw exceptions, after all, user could enter something like `^Chaha\b\b\bnot a number, you fool!`

Comment: If the print statement is correct, the condition should actually be: `x >= 10 && x <= 150`

Comment: True, I simply took in the data as a double[]... rounded in just to be safe, then converted to int[], and returned said array. thanks for the idea !!

Comment: @wxyz yeah, my bad, I just changed the inequalities without changing the logical connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just catch the exception and handle it, using a `while (true)` to allow the user to re-try.

Here's my code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.print("\nInsert a number >>> ");
    try {
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You inserted " + x);
        if (x > 10 && x < 150) {
            System.out.print("x between 10 and 150: ");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("x must be an int between 10 and 150");
        sc.nextLine(); //This line is really important, without it you'll have an endless loop as the sc.nextInt() would be skipped. For more infos, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8043307/1094430
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: yep. The best one. +1

Comment: a do while never is the best solution, besides that `x between 10 and 150` should be `x> 10 && x < 150`

Comment: I never use the `do-while` but the OP used it and I didn't want to change his code. Thanks for the advice on the and, I forgot to change it when I fixed his inital condition.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need an additional check. The exception is just there so you can act accordingly in your program. After all, it doesn't really matter how exactly the input was wrong. Just catch the exception (NumberFormatException, I guess?) and upon catching it, print an error message:

```
while (true) try {
    // here goes your code that pretends only valid inputs can occur
    break;   // or better yet, put this in a method and return
} catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {  // or whatever is appropriate
    System.err.println("You're supposed to enter integral values.");
    // will repeat due to while above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass {                                                         
    public static void main(String args[]) {                                     
        double x = 150.999; // 1
        /* int x = (int) 150.999; */ // 2                                          
        if ( x >= 10 && x <= 150 ) { // The comparison will still work                                             
            System.out.print("x between 10 and 150: " + x + "\n");               
        }                                                                        
    }                                                                            
}
```

1. Declare x as double, comparisons between double and int will still work.
2. Or, cast the number and any decimal values will be discarded.